# Extracting numeric-only columns and then passing that matrix to heatmap() in R

Tags: r, correlation, heatmap

I used the following code:

```
data<-read.csv('/Users/mf/Desktop/acceptor.csv')
just_nums<-sapply(data,is.numeric)
just_nums_data<-data[,just_nums]
str(just_nums_data)
heatmap(just_nums_data)
```

But got this output:

```
data<-read.csv('/Users/mf/Desktop/acceptor.csv')
just_nums<-sapply(data,is.numeric)
just_nums_data<-data[,just_nums]
str(just_nums_data)
'data.frame':   622 obs. of  16 variables:
 ID                                 : int  1 2 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 ...
 QnWeight_initial                   : int  158 165 137 129 155 150 119 153 137 153 ...
 QnWeight_initial_mg                : num  15.8 16.5 13.7 12.9 15.5 15 11.9 15.3 13.7 15.3   ....
 Days_till_1st_Wrkr                 : int  NA 21 NA 26 NA 23 22 20 22 NA ...
 Days_before_max_Wrkr_Eclosion      : int  NA 12 NA 7 NA 10 11 13 11 NA ...
 Wrkr_Eclosion_Bin                  : int  NA 3 NA 1 NA 1 2 3 2 NA ...
 QnMass_At_Wrkr_Eclosion            : int  NA 83 NA 73 NA 67 53 78 56 NA ...
 ColonyMass_At_Wrkr_Eclosion        : int  NA 117 NA 53 NA 91 85 111 96 NA ...
 Adult_Wrkrs_At_Wrkr_Eclosion       : int  NA 9 NA 5 NA 1 7 3 2 NA ...
 Mature_Brood_At_Wrkr_Eclosion      : int  NA 25 NA 13 NA 17 18 27 28 NA ...
 Sum_wrkrsPlusBrood_At_Wrkr_Eclosion: int  0 34 0 18 0 18 25 30 30 0 ...
QnMass_2wksLater                   : int  NA 124 NA NA NA 111 NA NA NA NA ...
QnMass_4wksLater                   : int  NA 117 NA NA NA 88 NA NA NA NA ...
ColonyMass_4wksLater               : int  NA 571 NA NA NA 736 NA NA NA NA ...
QnMass_2mnthsLater                 : int  NA 118 NA NA NA 86 NA NA NA NA ...
ColonyMass_2mnthsLater             : int  NA 445 NA NA NA 1817 NA NA NA NA ...
heatmap(just_nums_data)
Error in heatmap(just_nums_data) : 'x' must be a numeric matrix
```

I guess my confusion lays in the fact that the type "int" satisfies is.numeric() but doesn't count as numeric when it is passed to heatmap(). Is this what is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `heatmap` requires `x` to be a numeric matrix (see `?heatmap`).
- It tests this by using `is.numeric(x)` 
  or more specifically a `numeric` object with 2 dimensions

  - `length(di <- dim(x)) != 2 || !is.numeric(x)`)
- a `data.frame` is not a numeric matrix, even if all the columns are numeric

For example:

```
.d <- data.frame(x= 1:10, y = runif(10))
is.numeric(.d) 
## [1] FALSE
```

So, you would need to run

```
heatmap(as.matrix(just_nums_data))
```

Comment: Just saw your answer after I posted my comment. +1